# How do I generate the following statements in SystemVerilog using a loop?

Tags: system-verilog, programming-loop

```
parameter WIDTH = 512;

wire [0][(WIDTH-1)/1:0][15:0] tree;
wire [1][(WIDTH-1)/2:0][15:0] tree;
wire [2][(WIDTH-1)/4:0][15:0] tree;
wire [3][(WIDTH-1)/8:0][15:0] tree;
wire [4][(WIDTH-1)/16:0][15:0] tree;
wire [5][(WIDTH-1)/32:0][15:0] tree;
wire [6][(WIDTH-1)/64:0][15:0] tree;
wire [7][(WIDTH-1)/128:0][15:0] tree;
wire [8][(WIDTH-1)/256:0][15:0] tree;
wire [9][(WIDTH-1)/512:0][15:0] tree;
```

Comment: wire [i][(WIDTH-1)/((9-i)**2):0][15:0] tree;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get compiling errors with the provided sample code:

1. `tree` is redefined in the same scope
2. Packed dimension must specify a range

   - `wire [1][(WIDTH-1)/1:0][15:0] tree;` is illegal
   - `wire [1:1][(WIDTH-1)/1:0][15:0] tree;` is legal

You need to use the generate construct adopted from IEEE1364-2001 that has been extended into SystemVerilog. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 27 *Generate construct* for full details on usage.

Using a generate loop will give scope control of the `tree` name since each loop is a sub scope preventing name conflict. adding a label to the loop allows easy referece to the desired scope. What you are looking for is likely:

```
for(genvar i=0; i<10;i++) begin : label
  wire [(WIDTH-1)/(2**i):0][15:0] tree;
end
```

You can access each label via the label identifier loop index. Example:

- `label[0].tree` has `[511/1:0][15:0] tree`
- `label[1].tree` has `[511/2:0][15:0] tree`
- ...
- `label[8].tree` has `[511/256:0][15:0] tree`
- `label[9].tree` has `[511/512:0][15:0] tree`

If you need the first index, you might want to try:

```
for(genvar i=0; i<10;i++) begin : label
  wire [i:0][(WIDTH-1)/(2**i):0][15:0] tree; //packed range
end
```

or:

```
for(genvar i=0; i<10;i++) begin : label
  wire [(WIDTH-1)/(2**i):0][15:0] tree [i+1]; //packed range, "tree[i+1]" equiv "tree[i:0]"
end
```